# $\int f'g'$ given $f$ and $g$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose I know $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Are there any tricks or techniques for finding $\int f'(x)g'(x) dx$? Or other possible forms of $\int f'(x)g'(x) dx$ that might be useful?

(The title contains the meat of the question.)

Comment: No, in general you do not find $\displaystyle \int f' g' \ \mathrm dx$ from $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thanks! Any reasoning or explanation regarding that?

Comment: integration by parts perhaps?

Comment: @user29418 that wouldn't work

Comment: @Alex the analog of product rule in integration is integration by part, so, not really product rule in integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $f(x) = g(x) = e^{x^2}$, $f'(x) = g'(x) = 2xe^{x^2}$.

However, $\displaystyle \int f'(x) g'(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int 4x^2 e^{2x^2} \ \mathrm dx = x e^{2x^2} - \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4} \operatorname{erfi}(\sqrt 2x)$ is non-elementary (thanks to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E2+e%5E(2x%5E2)+dx)).

---

We have the product rule of differentiation: $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$.

If we integrate both sides, we get $fg = \displaystyle \int (f'g + fg') \ \mathrm dx$.

Rearranging terms gives us $\displaystyle \int fg' \ \mathrm dx = fg - \int f'g \ \mathrm dx$.

Absorbing derivatives gives $\displaystyle \int f \ \mathrm dg = fg - \int g \ \mathrm df$.

This is the integration by part.

So, you can't really convert the product rule to an analog in integration.

Comment: What did you set for $g$ in the example? I assume it's $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: @5xum yes, sorry